# How does smtp server send messages

Tags: php, email, smtp, server-side

I can send message to another mailbox via some smtp server. But I want to know is it possible to avoid a connection to a `SMTP` server and communicate along with the server in which reciever mailbox is located. 
For instance: I want to send message from `yahoo` mailbox to a google mailbox. I'm connectin to the `yahoo` smtp server. Now some `smtp`-server command like the follwoing:

```
EHLO myname
auth login
mail from: test@yahoo.com
rcpt to: test@google.com
data
This is a test message
.
```

And after this commands `yahoo` smtp sevrver is magically sending my message to the `google` mailbox. But I want to know how does smtp servers sending this messages? How can I to implements using `php` a `tiny-smtp-server`?

Answer (score 0):

The mail server(s) responsible for a domain will be looked up with DNS by asking for the MX record of the domain:

```
$ dig mx google.com
...
google.com.             19      IN      MX      10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             19      IN      MX      20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             19      IN      MX      30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             19      IN      MX      40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.             19      IN      MX      50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
...
```

So you might try to do such an MX lookup and then talk to the server directly.

But, with all the spam today most larger providers don't accept mails from anybody, e.g. if you want to send a mail to somebody@google.com from yourself@google.com you might need to authorize yourself and if you send mail from yourself@google.com to somebody@yahoo.com the mail server for yahoo might look up the SPF records for google.com and check, that you are in the allowed list of sender IPs.

In summary: the easiest and most reliable way is to use the mail server given to you by your mail provider and let them deal with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "magical"; Yahoo's server performs a similar dialog with Google's SMTP server.  If there were not a lot of spam fighting in between (mainly port blocking) you could connect directly to Google's SMTP server yourself, but these days, you have to relay via your own ISP.  Once upon a time, direct-to-MX SMTP was the norm.

The part which is slightly more "magical" is how individual SMTP servers deliver into a local mail storage.  This is not standardized, but typical set-ups include delivery straight into a local `mbox` file (appending to `/var/spool/you` on the Unix server where you read your mail), or storing in a POP or IMAP server's message store.